# How right use karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, templates

I have directive:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('stat24hour', stat24hour);

function stat24hour(req) {
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        template: 'scripts/widgets/templates/stat24Hour.html'
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope) {
        req.option('stats').then(function(data){
            scope.stats = data;
        });
    }
}
```

And i configure karma to make my templates *.html like module

```
(function(module) {
try {
  module = angular.module('template');
} catch (e) {
  module = angular.module('template', []);
}
module.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('scripts/widgets/templates/stat24Hour.html','Here HTML');
});
})();
```

But when i try to use

```
    angular.module('template');
inject(function($compile, $rootScope){
    compile = $compile;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var element = angular.element('div stat24hour');
    var compiledElement = compile(element)(scope);
    console.log(compiledElement);
});
```

Compile return html without template from directive.
What need fix to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

you have template: '..' in your directive, you should use templateUrl, when loading an external resource. template: means a static string as template